# exclude multiple paths in s3 using python

Tags: python

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/s3list.py", line 9, in <module>
    if exclude_paths not in key['Key']:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

Script:

```
from boto3 import client
exclude_paths=('DC','A')
conn = client('s3') 

for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket='my-bucket')['Contents']:  
       if exclude_paths not in key['Key']:
         print(key['Key'])
```

With one path is working but i need to have it work with multiple paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exclude_paths` is a tuple, not a string.

So instead of your

```
   if exclude_paths not in key['Key']:
```

use

```
   if key['Key'] not in exclude_paths:
```

---

*Addendum:*

If you want to print paths which don't *start* with a string in your exclude `exclude_paths`, use

```
    if not key['Key'].startswith(exclude_paths):
```

instead of your original `if` statement.

Comment: Yes i tried this but it doesn't give me the result that i want.  It brings me this: A/
A/B/
DC/
DC/LastAWRReport-200607-103252.html
DC/LastAWRReport-200607-104438.html
DC/LastAWRReport-200607-123731.html
DC/hs_err_pid1003103.log
DC/hs_err_pid257708.log
DC/hs_err_pid367738.log
test/
test/terraform.tfstate
test/terraform2.tfstate
test/tomcat1.nps
test/tomcat2.nps
I want what starts with A and DC to be excluded.

Comment: I wrote it in my answer as addendum.

Comment: Thank you, it works with  "if not key['Key'].startswith(exclude_paths):" .

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer (click on the checkmark near top of it) and upvote it (click on the upper triangle) if it was useful for you. This is a preferred way how to express “thank you” in this site.

Answer (score 0):

your code is testing if a tuple is in string. It cant work.

see the code below

```
from boto3 import client
exclude_paths=('DC','A')
conn = client('s3') 

for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket='my-bucket')['Contents']:  
       if key['Key'] not in exclude_paths:
         print(key['Key'])
```